# DotNetNuke. How to get current url or ID of page (and frontpage)?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I`m use my custom template. In file CustomTemplate.ascx need to control somethings elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your control inherits from PortalModuleBase you will have a property called "TabId" that will give you the id of the current page.

To get the URL for that page you can use `DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateUrl(TabId);`

To get the URL for the homepage, you can use `PortalSettings.HomeTabId` and the same NavigateUrl Method.

Comment: Be aware that Request.RawUrl will give you the rewritten Url, not the requested Url - see my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

The current Url is also obtained by using the Context.Items("UrlRewrite:OriginalUrl").  This is the Url the page was requested with (which is different to the Request.Url or Request.RawUrl value, which is the rewritten Url.